# How does a Hypervisor know a VM needs CPU time?

Tags: virtual-machine

So I know some (if not all) major Hyper-visors are capable of scheduling more CPU time for more needy guests, while throttling down the CPU time of idle ones.

How does the Hypervisor know if a guest is spending it's time idling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with: what does a normal computer do? When it's idle, it sends idle instructions to the CPU, and the CPU turns itself off for a bit. (This is a dramatic over-simplification, but accurate enough for this question.)

Some thing happens in a VM: the Hypervisor intercepts the idle instruction if another VM has instructions pending, otherwise it idles the processor itself.

Comment: There might be something more modern that I'm not aware of, but yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Modern OS's put the CPU into an idle state, (mostly) shutting the CPU down to wait for the next interrupt - this process is caught by the Hypervisor, allowing it to suspend the VM until it needs to be woken up.